# Auto-indenting C code with tabs for blocks and spaces for other wrapping?

Tags: indentation, whitespace

Is it possible to setup emacs to indent C code, with tabs for blocks `{ ... }` and spaces with other wrapping (argument, for example)?

Eg:

```
<-->if (foo) {
<--><-->function(a, b,
<--><-->.........c, d);
<-->}
```

Currently emacs uses tabs with spaces for padding.

```
<-->if (foo) {
<--><-->function(a, b,
<--><--><--><-->.c, d);
<-->}
```

(where `<-->` is for tabs and `.` for spaces).

QtCreator has the option to: *Align continuation lines --> with spaces*.

Is this possible in emacs?

---

Update, I wasn't aware at time of asking but this is sometimes called *"smart-tabs"*.

Comment: This is more commonly known as "Smart Tabs", there's at least one Emacs package out there for it.